MariaDB shares simply disappeared from my portfolio. I later read that the company had been delisted from the stock exchange
I had quite a lot of MariaDB shares. I was about 90% in the red with them. I realized much too late that the MariaDB shares had simply disappeared from my portfolio. No sign of MariaDB shares at all.
I then found the following article with DDG:

The ailing database company MariaDB Corporation Ab is being taken over
by financial investor K1 and will therefore disappear from the stock
exchange. The company is the central developer and provider of the
open-source database management system of the same name, but also
offers commercial cloud packages.

Can anyone tell me what exactly was going on here and why I didn't get any info at all as to what these automations are?
I am based in Switzerland and use Swissquote (broker) if that matters.

K1 made a purchase offer which was accepted by shareholders representing 89% of the shares. Because the majority of shareholders accepted the offer, remaining shares were involuntarily sold to K1 on August 26, 2024. You should have received cash in the amount of 55 cents per share shortly after that date, so check your transaction history.
You should have gotten a notice from your broker at the end of July, you should check your notification settings, it may be a paperless notification you overlooked.
